# ActivityIndicator and Alert is not working together

Tags: react-native

```
validateLogin(){
    this.setState({
      isLoading: true
    });
    var params={
      UserName: this.state.email,
      PassWord: this.state.password
    }
    Api.validateLogin(params).then((res) => {
      var jsonResp=JSON.parse(res.d)[0];
      console.log(jsonResp)
      if(jsonResp.LoginSucess === 'Yes') {
        AsyncStorage.setItem("UserInfo", JSON.stringify(jsonResp));
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Dashboard')
      }
     else {
      Alert.alert(
        'AMS',
        'Invalid username or password.',
        [
          {text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed')},
        ],
        {cancelable: false},
      );
     }
     this.setState({
      isLoading: false
    });
    });
```

Am i missing anything?

I am trying to hide the Activity Indicator before alert and Alert should be dismissed on click of "OK" button.

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" style={styles.container} onPress={() => {Keyboard.dismiss()}}>
        <ActivityIndicatorLoader
          loading={this.state.isLoading} />
          <View style={[styles.box, styles.content]}>

            <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                <Icon style={styles.inputIcon} size={34} name="ios-contact" />
                <TextInput style={styles.inputs}
                  autoCapitalize="none"
                  placeholderTextColor="gray" 
                  placeholder="Username"
                  keyboardType="default"
                  underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
                  onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({email})}/>
            </View>


            <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
              <Icon style={styles.inputIcon} size={34} name="ios-key" />
              <TextInput style={styles.inputs}
                  placeholder="Password"
                  autoCapitalize="none"
                  secureTextEntry={true}
                  placeholderTextColor="gray" 
                  underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
                  onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({password})}/>
            </View>

            <TouchableHighlight underlayColor="gray" style={[btnStyles.buttonContainer, btnStyles.primaryButton]} onPress={() => this.onClickListener('sign_in')}>
              <Text style={btnStyles.btnText}>Sign In</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>

          </View>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

if credentials are incorrect then it should show the alert message and should hide the ActivityIndicator but Alert is showing for a second and automatically closed and activity-indicator is continuously showing for indefinite.

Comment: Have you tried doing `this.setState({
      isLoading: false
    });` before `Alert.alert`?

Comment: Yes. Tried but with same result.